# The ScrollView component has an accessibility issue as it prevents the user navigating to the back button

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated, react-native-reanimated-v2

We use react-navigation to open a modal with a back button. There is an accessibility problem with this setup as users can't "swipe" left from the title (within the ScrollView) to the back button. After a lot of investigation we pinned it down to the ScrollView component. If we change it to a regular View then there is no problem at all. However obviously this is not desired a the user should be able to scroll.

This is the problematic code.

```
import React, { FC, memo } from 'react'
import Animated, { useAnimatedScrollHandler } from 'react-native-reanimated'
import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'

import { useThemedStyle } from '@mylib/ui'

import { stylesCreator } from './styles'
import type { AnimatedScrollViewProps } from './types'

const AnimatedScrollViewComponent: FC<AnimatedScrollViewProps> = ({
  scrollOffset,
  children
}) => {
  const scrollHandler = useAnimatedScrollHandler(event => {
    scrollOffset.value = event.contentOffset.y
  })
  const { bottom: bottomInset } = useSafeAreaInsets()

  const styles = useThemedStyle(stylesCreator, bottomInset)

  return (
    <Animated.ScrollView
      style={styles.scrollContainer}
      contentContainerStyle={styles.contentContainer}
      scrollEventThrottle={50}
      onScroll={scrollHandler}
      overScrollMode="never"
    >
      {children}
    </Animated.ScrollView>
  )
}

export const AnimatedScrollView = memo(AnimatedScrollViewComponent)
```

We are kind of out options what to investigate next. So I'm hoping anyone has experience with this and can help us out in some way.

Comment: `There is an accessibility problem with this setup as users can't "swipe" left from the title (within the ScrollView) to the back button`. I have troubles to understand what this means. Could you elaborate?

Comment: It's about users having VoiceOver enabled. They navigate thru the elements on the page by swiping. Swipe right for the next and left previous. This is issue is about swiping left to back button. It's not working when coming from a ScrollView.